# why does the parentheses make a difference in this line of code

Tags: java

I was working on leetcode #112 and this is my solution:

```
    public boolean hasPathSum(TreeNode root, int targetSum) {
        if(root == null){
            return false;
        }
        return helper(root, targetSum);
    }
        private boolean helper(TreeNode root, int sum) {
            if(root.left == null && root.right == null) {
                return sum - root.val == 0;
            }
            
            return (root.left == null? false : helper(root.left, sum - root.val)) || 
                root.right == null? false : helper(root.right, sum - root.val);
        }
    
}
```

on the last return in the helper function, the test would only pass if there were parentheses around the ternary statements(shown around root.left). I was wondering why does the parenthese make a difference in this case?

Comment: For the only reason that they ever make a difference: because they change the order of operations. What is there not to understand?

Comment: I'd recommend you always use parens, if only to make your code more readable. Takes the guesswork out of operator precedence.

Comment: One should know operator precedence and associativity of their used operators. Introducing named intermediate variables for better clarity is IMHO superior to redundant parenthesis.

Comment: I definitely agree about adding parens to remove ambiguity. I've been programming professionally for about a decade and don't know all the operator precedence rules, especially around ternaries. If there's even a small risk of confusion, I add the parens and don't worry about arcane compiler rules. :)

Comment: It's the same reason why `(3+2)*5` gives a different result than `3+2*5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With parens, and boiling it down to bare essence, it's:

> `return (a ? false : b) || c ? false : d;`

Without them, it's resolved as:

`return a ? false : ((b || c) ? false : d);`

Answer (score 1):

From the used operators the precedence is as follows:

1. subtraction (left-to-right)
2. equality (left-to-right)
3. logical or (left-to-right)
4. ternary operator (right-to-left)

*where the upper ones overrule the lower*

So suppose you have two ternary operators intertwined like so:

```java
var value1 = a ? b : c || d ? e : f;
var value2 = (a ? b : c) || (d ? e : f);
var value3 = a ? b : (c || d) ? e : f;
var value4 = a ? b : ((c || d) ? e : f);
```

And `value1` has no parenthesis, therefore we will compute the logical or first, such that we arrive at the equation for `value3`.

In `value3` the next higher operator is the ternary operator, which is [right-associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), such that we will compute it as if we would put the right-most ternary calculation in parenthesis as in equation for `value4`.

Now you should clearly see, that solution for `value4` differs very much from the one for `value2`.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html
https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/